# Download a p7m file from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2005, vbscript

I have the following problem, I insert a p7m file into a `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server 2005.

When from a classic asp page I try to download it with the following vbscript code:

```
Dim sSql, oCmd, nomeric
Set oCmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = OBJdbConnection
oCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

sSql = "SELECT fileP7m FROM tabella "

Response.ContentType = "application/pkcs7-mime"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & nomeric

oCmd.CommandText = sSql

oCmd.Properties("Output Stream").Value = Response
oCmd.Execute , , 1024

Set oCmd = nothing
```

The file is downloaded correctly, and it is possible to open it with Adobe Acrobat normally, but if I submit the file into a site to verify the digital sign, it fails, while the original file worked well.

If I open the file downloaded with notepad++ and the original one the first contains some very strange characters, something like Chinese or Indian, I really don't know. Where is the error that makes me transform the file p7m in that way? Why is it impossible to verify the digital sign?

Thank you 
Best regards.

For completeness, I also write the way I insert the file into the database.
`pContent` is the string containing the whole file p7m.

```
Dim currFileStream, oCmd, i
SET oCmd = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
SET currFileStream = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Stream")

currFileStream.Type = 2
currFileStream.Open

For i = 1 To Len(pContent)
    currFileStream.WriteText ChrB(Asc(Mid(pContent, i, 1)))
Next

oCmd("@fileAttached").AppendChunk currFileStream.Read(currFileStream.Size)
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("@fileAllegato", adLongVarBinary, adParamInput, currFileStream.Size)
```

A stored procedure run the insert in the column `fileAttached`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Because the following stream cut last charatcter , i add an empty char as binary

### This solution works

```
 sSql =  "SELECT fileAllegato + CAST(' ' AS varbinary(1)) fileAllegato " & _
                "FROM Table"

        oCmd.CommandText = sSql
        set rc_file = oCmd.Execute
        if rc_file.EOF then 
            set oCmd = nothing
            Response.Write ("Allegato 
            non trovato.")
        else 
            fileall = rc_file("fileAllegato")
        end if  

        rc_file.close
        set rc_file = nothing

        Const adTypeText = 2
        Const adTypeBinary = 1

        Dim BinaryStream
        Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        BinaryStream.Open
        BinaryStream.Write fileall 

        BinaryStream.Position = 0
        BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText

        Dim BinaryToString:BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText(-1) 

        BinaryStream.Close
        Set BinaryStream = Nothing

        Response.ContentType = "application/pkcs7-mime"
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & nomefile
        Response.BinaryWrite BinaryToString
```